# bulk join json with jpg from Google Takeout not working

Tags: json, gif, bulk, exiftool

I'm following the existing post: [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65210140/how-to-merge-json-and-google-takeout-photos-to-get-the-right-dates-back) and the script is running and modifying all my gifs (according to the output of the cmd prompt...) but the actual createdate and modified date are not changing.

Anyone got a clue why it just doesn't seem to do what it implies it is doing?

Thanks!

```
I'm running this: 

exiftool -r -d %s -tagsfromfile "%d/%F.json" "-DateTimeOriginal<PhotoTakenTimetimestamp" "-ModifyDate<PhotoTakenTimetimestamp" "-CreateDate<PhotoTakenTimetimestamp" -ext gif -overwrite_original "G:\Gifs2"

Based on example json:
```

"title": "PXL_20220302_175907506-ANIMATION.gif",
"description": "",
"imageViews": "9",
"creationTime": {
"timestamp": "1646328152",
"formatted": "3 Mar 2022, 17:22:32 UTC"
},
"photoTakenTime": {
"timestamp": "1646243958",
"formatted": "2 Mar 2022, 17:59:18 UTC"
},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the File System time stamps with the embedded time stamps. Add this to your command, so that you will write embedded time stamps as well as file system time stamps

```
"-FileModifyDate<PhotoTakenTimetimestamp" "-FileCreateDate<PhotoTakenTimetimestamp"
```

Comment: Ah!!! Thank you! That was driving me insane hahaha!